# Ignore SMTP exception errors on cakephp 3.6.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a user management system that sends email every day to expiring customers

It works with my smtp settings but some resellers set their SMTP configs wrong and it breaks my cron job with the exception:

> SMTP server did not accept the password. in
> [/home/enrico/Documentos/www/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Mailer/Transport/SmtpTransport.php,
> line 260]

this is the code:

```
$tls = $servidorEmail->seguranca == "TLS" ? true : false; 
                $email = new Email();
                $email->configTransport('personalizado', [
                    'className' => 'Smtp',
                    'host' => $servidorEmail->servidor,
                    'port' => $servidorEmail->porta,
                    'timeout' => 30,
                    'username' => $servidorEmail->usuario,
                    'password' => $servidorEmail->senha,
                    'client' => null,
                    'tls' => $tls,
                    'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
                ]);
                
                $email->transport('personalizado')
                    ->template('novo_cliente', 'notifica')
                    ->viewVars(['content' => $mensagem])
                    ->emailFormat('html')
                    ->to($entity->email)
                    ->from($servidorEmail->email)
                    ->subject($template->assunto);
                    
                $enviar = $email->send();
```

I tried to use Try and Catch on the $email->send() but it did not work.
How can i ignore those exceptions and keep sending emails to others users?

Comment: What exception were you trying to catch?

Comment: Im trying to ignore the exception at all and keep sending emails. I managed to igonre it using phpmailer with `try { $email->send(); } catch {}` that way my code keeps executing. I wanted to know how to do it in cakephp without phpmailer since try catch seens to not work at all in cakephp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706102/1127933

Comment: I use try/catch all the time in Cake. It's a language feature, not a framework feature, so Cake literally cannot *stop* it from working. That's why I'm asking what exception you're trying to catch, my guess would be you're looking for the wrong one.